# Rewrite does not seem to be recognizing my regex

Tags: .htaccess

I have this in my htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /myTest    

RewriteRule    ^/members/.+$    /members.php?a=$1
```

It's basically supposed to rewrite members.php?a=login to work with /members/login but it doesn't seem to be working. Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Not sure if this is worth mentioning but I'm running on port 81

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^members/(.+)$ members.php?a=$1
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to work, is it worth mentioning that I'm not on port 80?

Comment: And I don't know for your base... but if it's the root, you can delete It or you need to delete the / before /members.php

Comment: The port change nothing

Comment: Try with my edit, and if it does not work 
Give an example of an URL before and after the required rewriting